# Building a fluid mosaic grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a fluid mosaic grid. I used the fluid word since i already have a working mosaic grid. 
You can check a fiddle i made on purpose for this question: https://jsfiddle.net/a995w8ye/

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divContainer">
            <div id="1" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="4" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="5" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="6" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="7" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="8" class="cube">
            </div>
            <div id="9" class="cube">
            </div>
            </div> <!-- End of div container -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
#divContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cube {
    position:  relative;
float: left;
width: calc(1000px/3);
height: calc(800px/3);
cursor: pointer;
}

.cube.fullscreen{
    z-index: 9; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    background-color: #131313; 
}

.cube:hover {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

JS:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function fillColors(){
    for (var i = 1; i<=9; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(i).style.background = getRandomColor();
    }
}

window.onload=function(){

fillColors();

$('.cube').on('click', function() {

    $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
    $('.cube').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('fullscreen'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        $(this).hide();
    })
})
}
```

The width and height if each cube are 1/3 of the main div. They are left float and they have a relative position. I need a relative position since the "divContainer" in the real case doesn't have a fixed size and in that case, since all cubes have exactly 1/3(width and height) of it they will make a perfect grid that can be 3x3 or even 1x9.

When a user click in a cube, that cube get's another class with a higher z-index and the width and heigh equal to his parent. The other cubes won't be visible in the end. They might or might not disappear. In the end I just want to see the expanded cube that i clicked.

This is simple. What i want to do is to make a cube expand slowly while the others vanish slowly as well or at least cover the others with a higher z-index. This is easy to achieve in the top left cube using **.animate()** but in the middle cube or the bottom right one i find difficult to do this.

P.S: ATM I'm not worried about everything come back to his original state. I just want to expand every div as mentioned.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

I've fixed the code based on your comment

```js
var container = $('#container'),
    cubes = $('#container > div'),
    count = 3, unit = 'vw',
    fullstate = false;

function randomcolor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function fillcolor(){ 
  $(this).css({background: randomcolor()});
}

function setup () { 
  var t = $(this),
      i = t.index();
  t.data({
    top: Math.floor(i/count) * 100/count,
    left: (i%count) * 100/count
  });
}

function gridposition () {
  var t = $(this);
  t.css({
    'z-index': 0,
    top: t.data('top') + unit,
    left: t.data('left') + unit,
    width: 100/count + unit,
    height: 100/count + unit
  });
}

function fullcube () {
  $(this).css({
    'z-index': 9,
    width: 100 + unit,
    height: 100 + unit,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  });
}

cubes.each(function () {
  setup.call(this);
  fillcolor.call(this);
  gridposition.call(this);
}).on('click', function () {
  if (fullstate) {
    cubes.each(gridposition);
  } else {
    fullcube.call(this);
  }
  fullstate = !fullstate;  
});
```

```css
html, 
body, 
#container,
#container > div.fullscreen  {  
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container > div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
</div>
```

---

OLD ANSWER

This is how I would solve this problem:

```js
var container = $('#container'),
    cubes = $('#container > div');

function randomcolor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function fillcolor(){ 
  $(this).css({background: randomcolor()});
}

cubes.each(fillcolor).on('click', function () {
  var h = 'hidden';
  cubes.toggleClass(h);
  $(this).removeClass(h).toggleClass('fullscreen');
});
```

```css
html, 
body, 
#container,
#container > div.fullscreen  {  
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container > div {
  float: left;
  width: 32vw; height: 32vw;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#container > div:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

#container > div.hidden {
  width: 0; height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The toggle makes the other cubes get smaller and smaller until their gone. This makes a weird behaviour in the grid causing blank spots (or the background color of the main div) while in transition.
My idea was the clicked cube grow in the top of the others. The other cubes might or might not disappear. In the end they aren't suppose to be visible.

Comment: Updated the answer to fill your needs ... hope you like it! ;D

Comment: Can't give you anymore up-votes. It worked like i wanted. In fact since you initiate everything in the javascript I can add variables to set the size I want easily. Thanks